# xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '12.1'

Tags: xcodebuild

I am not a coder but a Functional QA guy trying to setup Appium on mac to get some hands on mobile automation. Ok so now, I followed below instructions on tutorial site:

Launch Xcode and create a new project. Select the Tabbed App template and then give it any product name that you want.

Now in terminal, change your directory to your project directory and compile a simulator-compatible .app build with the following command

xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator12.1 which gives me error

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.1

xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '12.1'.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie you can try [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/). They have the object spy feature which would be easier for you to identify the elements, and they support different languages like Java, C#, ruby ...